# How to delete DataRow from DataTable on RowCommand

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable

I'm trying to delete the selected row in a gridview from the datatable but it seems like it's not deleting. in if statment Table.Rows.Count = 0 is not working and I'm trying this with one row in the grid view.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

    Dim Table As New DataTable
    Table = GridView1.DataSource
    Dim iOriPrice As Double
    iOriPrice = Table.Rows(index).Item("sPrice")
    Table.Rows(index).Delete()
    'reset table and set to gridview
    If Table.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Table.Reset()
        GridView1.DataSource = Table
        GridView1.DataBind()
        lblTotalAm.Text = ""
        lblTotalMsg.Text = "Shopping Cart is empty"
        Session.Add("BuyTable", Table)
        btnBuyNow.Visible = False
    Else
        'calculate total sum and 
        Dim newTotal As Double
        newTotal = Convert.ToDouble(lblTotalAm.Text) - iOriPrice
        lblTotalAm.Text = newTotal
        Session.Add("BuyTable", Table)
        GridView1.DataSource = Table
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does `index` come from in  `Table.Rows(index).Delete()` ?

Anyway, this `Delete()` only marks the record for deletion *in memory*. You need to add an `Adapter.Update()` to delete it from the database.

Comment: thanks you led me to the answer. 
        Table.Rows(index).Delete()
        Table.AcceptChanges()